# Replicating the Waves key derivation process with js libraries

Tags: javascript, cryptography, wavesplatform

I'm following this [documentation page](https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/blockchain/waves-protocol/data-structures.html) to figure out the relationship between a public key, a Waves testnet address, and a Waves mainnet address.

I'm written this code snippet, putting in a pub key and address I got from Waves Keeper:

```
const base58 = require('bs58')
const blake2b = require('blakejs')
const keccak = require('keccak256')

const pubKey_58 = '4DRwrsAPmw4aJ421WLhkLQwSojHbtGEX9TJA7ALWJfUf'
const pubKey_hex = base58.decode(pubKey_58)
const pubKey_blake = blake2b.blake2bHex(pubKey_hex, null, 32)
const pubKey_kck = keccak(pubKey_blake)

console.log(`Key base58: ${pubKey_58}`)
console.log(`Key hex: ${pubKey_hex.toString('hex')}`)
console.log(`Key blake: ${pubKey_blake.toString('hex')}`)
console.log(`\nKeccak of blake (real vs expected short) \nRe: ${pubKey_kck.toString('hex')}\nEx: 42277bd8eaff21ec56624ab8c003f70673510e74`)
```

Here is the output I get:
[image]

Clearly, the manually derived address is different. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

you can also get the address from public key using the built-in function:

```
addressFromPublicKey(publicKey: ByteVector): Address
```